# How to find all the strings in an application's memory

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find all the strings in a java application's memory. (Like process hacker does). However, when I use process hacker, I get strings that my program can't detect.

Also, I'm pretty sure I'm looping through this one character at a time, is there a way I can fix this, while preventing ReadProccessMemory from returning fragments of strings? (I.e. if the memory is like oiuwlkme**MySting**lkjalkwj I want to make sure **MyString** doesn't get split up, into two different strings (like oiuwlkme**MySti** *and* **ng**lkjalkwj)

Here's my code so far:

```
        const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;//?
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess,
      Int64 lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //doMemorySharp();
        //Console.ReadLine();
        //return;

        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("javaw")[0];
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);
        IntPtr startOffset = process.MainModule.BaseAddress;
        IntPtr endOffset = IntPtr.Add(startOffset, process.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[48];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < process.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize; i++)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;
            buffer = new byte[48];
            if (!ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, IntPtr.Add(startOffset, i).ToInt64(), buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("false");
            }

            string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
            if (s.Contains("MyString"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yay!");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(fromByteArray(buffer));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.WriteLine("Memory:" + process.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the first thing you should do in to increase the buffer size to make your scanner healthier and faster. This will not prevent the problem from happening, but it's still helpful:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
```

If the processes are not too big (on the point of view of memory consumption) you could dump their whole memory with a single `ReadProcessMemory` call and then perform a fast binary scan on the dump.

Another way is to keep on scanning their memory by chunks as you are already doing and, as soon as you spot a piece of text that partially matches the beginning your string:

- revert back the current offset to the beginning of that piece of text
- read the small memory area between `OffsetBegin` and `OffsetBegin + TargetStringLength`
- check if the content of your buffer matches the target string